# Maintaining GREP variables through find and replace

Tags: grep, replace

I've recently taken on a project of document conversion to HTML. That is, a client gives me a .DOC file, and I need to convert the contents to one long HTML file - no styling, no CSS, just clean HTML with paragraph tags, header tags tags, etc.

I found an application that does a pretty good job of automating the first part of it. The problem is that I need to do some advanced find and replace based on strings using variables.

For instance, I have footnotes that were converted properly. They're currently displayed as superscript numbers with the

I'd like to change how the footnote is displayed. Instead of a superscript number 6 for the 6th footnote, I'd like it to show (Note 6)

To do that on the entire document (hundreds of footnotes), I'm wondering if I can do something like:

FIND:

```
<sup><a name="FN[0-9]" href="FNR[0-9]">[0-9]</a></sup>
```

REPLACE:

```
<a name="FN%1" href="FNR%2">(Note %3)</a>
```

The problem is, I can't find a Find and Replace tool that lets me maintain the variables in the replace area. All I get is the superscript 6 appearing as (Note %3), as well as every other footnote doing the same thing.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish my task efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

In Perl it would look roughly like this on the command line (I have NOT tested this):

```
perl -i -p -e's{<sup><a name="(FN\d)" href="(FNR\d)">(\d)</a></sup>}{<a name="$1" href="$2">(Note $3)</a>}' filenames....
```

`-i` says "Edit this file in place", `-p` means "print each line after we do whatever is in the `-e` switch".

That's assuming you're only looking for a single digit where you have `[0-9]`.  If you want to match FN427, then you change `(FN\d)` to `(FN\d+)`, for example.

This also assumes that the HTML that are you parsing looks EXACTLY LIKE THAT.  If you get some HTML that is `<a href=... name=...` (with the attributes in opposite order than you have) then it will break.  In that case, you'll want to use an HTML parser.

I hope that gives you enough to start with.